# C# Creating an instance of a class from type

Tags: java, c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I'm trying to get this functionality:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(dir.substring(6).replaceAll("/", ".") 
                       + file.getName().replaceAll(".java", ""));
Packet packet = (Packet)c.newInstance();
```

For any of you who are familliar with it, the above code is Java, it gets the class from a directory and then creates an instance of it, which is what I'm trying to do in C#

I've gotten about this far, and now I'm stuck...

```
  foreach(Type t in assembly.GetTypes())
  {
        if (t.BaseType == typeof(Packet))
        {
```

Basically I need to find a way to construct a class from the Type, then create an instance of it.

I've tried using the Activator, like so:

```
foreach(Type t in assembly.GetTypes())
{
      if (t.BaseType == typeof(Packet))
      {
           string namespaceName = t.Namespace;
           string className = t.Name;
           var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(namespaceName, className);
```

but I can't figure out how to reference it as a class instead of an ObjectHandle

Answer (score 6):

> Basically I need to find a way to construct a class from the Type, then create an instance of it.

A `Type` *is* a class (or a struct, etc). Once you've got an appropriate `Type`, there are various options for instantiating it... for example, [`Activator.CreateInstance()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance), or call [`Type.GetConstructors()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getconstructors), find the right constructor and then [invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ycw1y17(v=vs.110).aspx) it.

All of these approaches return `object`, so you'll need to cast:

```
Packet packet = (Packet) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I was using `Activator.CreateInstance(namespaceName, className);` which had to be assigned to an ObjectHandle and I couldn't do anything with it.

Comment: @Christian.tucker: Even if you'd been able to use an `ObjectHandle`, `Activator.CreateInstance` doesn't take a namespace and a type name - it takes an *assembly* name and a namespace-qualified type name.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are looking for `Activator.CreateInstance` method

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```